# Angular, Modal Dialog with Carousel

Tags: angular, angular-material, modal-dialog, carousel

Good Day,

I have a list of products and I am using Angular Material Modal dialog. What is the best practice for creating modal with Dynamic Content having carousel functionality like next and previous button in it to navigation more products without closing dialog modal.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-v5wltn

Comment: A next/previous button inside the dialog will not close the dialog.

Comment: did you understand question? i was looking for carousel in modal dialog

Comment: how can i minus -1 you on this?????? :D

Comment: You are asking for best practice and mention a next/previous button closing the dialog. Insert a previous button left of the image, a next button to the right and cycle through your products. Tadaa carousel.

Comment: did you ever working with angular? or did you bother to visit https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-v5wltn this link?

Comment: I do and i did. Your Stackblitz opens a small dialog containing the product you selected. If you are not able to make a simple carousel there, I think all hope is lost..

Comment: If i Couldn't make it done then its your turn to show me your skills ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think angular-image-viewer can be a best thing you can use instead of making your own carousel.
Check out with https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-image-viewe this documentation.
Check out this also https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-gallery-imageviewer

Answer (score 1):

You can use Material-carousel and find by using link below

```
https://github.com/gbrlsnchs/material2-carousel
```